# How can I get the minimum value from a comma separated cell containing number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I found this formula which I can get the max value form a cell containing comma separated numbers. How can I get the min value using a similar approach?

> =MATCH(1000,INDEX(FIND(","&ROW(INDIRECT("1:999"))&",",","&D2&","),0))

Cell content '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15'

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
=MIN(0+MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1, ",", REPT(" ",255)), 255*(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&(1+LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","")))))-1)+1,255))
```

Answer (score 1):

If one has FILTERXML:

```
=MIN(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"))
```

For the MAX, just replace the MIN with MAX.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also go with `FILTERXML`. But if your string always follows this pattern it seems like the smallest number is always found on the left before the first comma which you could make perfect use of!

```
=--LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1&",")-1)
```